# Multiplication of all elements in two lists

Tags: python, list

I want to multiply each number of list1 with each number of list2.
  For example:
`[1,2]*[1,2,3]` should return something like this:  `[1,2,3,2,4,6]`
                                                                                 I just want to know if there is any special function to calculate this, as it would take a lot of time to calculate this using a for loop.

Comment: You can use [`itertools.products`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get all of the pairs.  From there, you can pass them to a function to calculate each of their (arithmetic) products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple nested [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) will work:

```
lst1, lst2 = [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]

[x * y for x in lst1 for y in lst2]
# [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6]
```

To get all the pairs (the cartesian product) from the two lists, you can also use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product
[x * y for x, y in product(lst1, lst2)]
# [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this using dot products, as provided by `numpy` (I include this as an answer because you said you are looking for *any* special function, and are looking to optimize speed, though I agree it's not the most readable or straightforward method):

```
import numpy as np

lst1, lst2 = [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]

np.dot(np.array([lst1]).T, np.array([lst2])).flatten().tolist()
#[1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import itertools    

a = [1, 2]
b = [1, 2, 3]
result = []
for n in a:
    m = map(lambda x,y: x*y, b, itertools.repeat(n))
    result.extend(m)
```